# Что означает код выхода -1073741819 в c++

Tags: c++

(говорю сразу, не кидайтесь на меня, я новичек в c++) что означает код выхода -1073741819? я правильно понял(?) что эти коды означают ошибки и хочу понять что значит -1073741819

Comment: В 16-чной записи это `0xC0000005`. По такому коду больше нагуглите.

Comment: спасибо⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ошибка Segmentation fault, то бишь ошибка сегментации. Возможно где-то вышли за пределы массива или разыменовали nullptr

Comment: ну судя по всему это скорее всего 1 вариант, потому что условия появления ошибки очень похожи, спасибо 